# React / Redux - Cannot read property "XXX" of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, redux

This is something I have been stuck on for over 2 weeks, so this question is my final chance at figuring this out. I hope anyone can help me (as the problem is most likely something small / something I have missed)

---

Using Node, Redux and React, I am returning a collection from my Mongo database.
I am using react-redux "connect" to retrieve my data from my store As seen in my JSX below.

**JSX:**

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import {fetchArticle} from "../../actions/articleActions"
var classNames = require('classnames');
import GlobalHero from '../modules/GlobalHero.jsx';

@connect((store) => {
    return {article: store.article.article, fetching: store.article.fetching};
})

export default class Article extends React.Component {

    // BEFORE COMPONENT RENDER (For Everyhing else)
    constructor() {
        super();
        //sets initial state
        this.state = {
            page: "Article"
        };
    }

    // BEFORE COMPONENT RENDER (For Ajax / Dispatcher Events): get article Title / Thumbnail rows based on this.props.indexLimit
    componentWillMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props)
        this.props.dispatch(fetchArticle(this.props.params.id))
    }

    // ON COMPONENT RENDER
    componentDidMount = () => {}

    render() {

        if (this.props.fetching) {
            return (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>
                    <h2>{this.props.article.subTitle}</h2>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

So when I return "title" and "subTitle" in my JSX, it pulls everything through perfectly fine (see below):

```
  <h1>{this.props.article.title}</h1>
  <h2>{this.props.article.subTitle}</h2>
```

The data is also visible on my screen (see below):

> [image]

But... As soon as I add:

```
  <h3>{this.props.article.body.section1.text}</h3>
```

My page will not load, and my console returns:

> Cannot read property 'section1' of undefined

When I look at the state of my returned data in the console:

> [image]

As you can see, it returns 'section1' in the console, so I must be calling my 'section1' wrong in my JSX?

I'm thinking the problem may be to do with the fact that 'section1' is nested further into my mongo db collection than 'title' or 'subTitle' is.

Below I will show you the rest of my routes for this page - I have looked endlessly online and cannot pinpoint my problem.

**Action:**

```
import axios from "axios";
//var resourceUrl = "http://localhost:7777/api/schools";

export function fetchArticle(id) {

    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_ARTICLE"
        })
        axios.get('/api/article', {
                params: {
                    id: id
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_ARTICLE_FULFILLED",
                    payload: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_ARTICLE_REJECTED",
                    payload: err
                })
            })
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    article: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_ARTICLE":
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: true
                }
            }
        case "FETCH_ARTICLE_REJECTED":
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    error: action.payload
                }
            }
        case "FETCH_ARTICLE_FULFILLED":
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    fetched: true,
                    article: action.payload,
                }
            }
    }
    return state
}
```

**Store:**

```
import {
    applyMiddleware,
    createStore
} from "redux"

import logger from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"

import reducer from "./reducers"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())

export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

**Node / Express Call:**

```
app.get('/api/article', (req, res) => {

    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var articles;

    db.collection('articles')
        .findOne({
            "_id": ObjectId("58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a")
        })
        .then(result => {
            articles = result;
        }).then(() => {
            res.send(articles);
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });

});
```

**The Record in my mongo DB collection:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58c2a5bdf36d281631b3714a"
    },
    "title": "EntertheBadJah",
    "subTitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "thmbNailImg": "",
    "headerImg": "",
    "body": {
        "section1": {
            "include": true,
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico posse integre cum ut, praesent iudicabit tincidunt te sea, ea populo semper laoreet duo."
        },
        "section2": {
            "include": true,
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico posse integre cum ut, praesent iudicabit tincidunt te sea, ea populo semper laoreet duo."
        },
        "bodyImg": {
            "include": true,
            "img": ""
        },
        "section3": {
            "include": true,
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dico posse integre cum ut, praesent iudicabit tincidunt te sea, ea populo semper laoreet duo."
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "recourse": {
            "include": false,
            "text": "Go watch their interview",
            "link": ""
        },
        "soundcloud": {
            "include": true,
            "link": "www.soundcloud.com/BadJah"
        },
        "spotify": {
            "include": false,
            "link": ""
        },
        "youtube": {
            "include": false,
            "link": ""
        },
        "twitter": {
            "include": false,
            "link": ""
        },
        "facebook": {
            "include": false,
            "link": ""
        },
        "instagram": {
            "include": false,
            "link": ""
        }
    },
    "keywords": "Badjah",
    "date": "",
    "author": "Aagentah",
    "dateAdded": "2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

---

Any help or advice on this problem is appreciated - thank you in advance.

Comment: @barbsan - I don't think so, as 'section1' is inside 'body'.

Comment: See the bottom snippet on this question: title and subTitle are a layer above from section1 @barbsan

Comment: I know nothing about react & redux. But this seems scary similar to an issue I encountered when learning RxJS within Angular2. There I had access to something called 'Elvis operator'. eg: `this.props.article.body?.section1.text` that would handle items that where loaded async (which it almost seems like section1 gets loaded that way)

Comment: If the object is equivelant to the object show above, then it seems like your calling it correctly. if you debug the this.props.article.body in your components render, does it provide undefined?

Comment: In my console the section1 has data @KornholioBeavis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React will rerender the page when its props (provided via Redux connect) change.  Since you're only firing off the request to fetch the data in `componentWillMount`, by definition this will not have completed on the first render.  However, that's no problem in the first case as `this.props.article` is guaranteed to be an object, `[]`, so `this.props.article.title` will just be `undefined`.  Once the request to the API returns, `article` is updated in the store and the page renders with the expected content.

However, since `this.props.article` is initially `[]`, if you try to render `this.props.article.body.section1.text`, your code will throw an exception as observed since whilst `article` is an object, `article.body` is `undefined`.  Having already thrown an error, the component will then fail to rerender when the article as actually updated in the store.

You need to add a guard to check the shape of `this.props.article` before trying to render subkeys, or else add a more complete default to the store for before the request returns with the actual article.

Comment: Ahhh I see, how should I be adding this guard in my code?

Comment: one example in the above answer.

Comment: Ahh okay, what would be good practice for checking my entire article, rather than just one object, as ideally I wouldn't want a check function for every single property, or would I?

Comment: I have similar issue with selector. In my case component gets UI-rendered as second re-render happens quite quickly, but in console i have an error mentioned above. To test an issue i wrote this "guard":
```modules: this.isApplicationsFetching && this.isModulesFetching ? `` : moduleSelectors.selectModulesByApplicationId(state, { applicationId: this.appid }),
```
which proved to me that selector at first render can't select anything by that `appid`. I am still in search for right solution, but will leave this comment there.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this. Could be that in the first render cycles its just not present yet.

```
checkRender(){
      typeof this.props.article.body === 'undefined' 
      ? return null 
      : return this.props.article.body.section1.text
    }
```

Then use it ::>

```
<h3>{checkRender}</h3>
```

Comment: Ahh okay, what would be good practice for checking my entire article, rather than just one object, as ideally I wouldn't want a check function for every single property, or would I?

Comment: You could make an HOC which checks all the props and then just wrap it around your components.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitely recommend to add Flow type checks to your codebase (http://flow.org). It can be added on a file-per-file basis but can help significantly in debugging these kind of problems.